# Custom Type Converter doesn't work in Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to build custom automapper type converter:

```
public class EnumDescriptor<TSource> where TSource: Enum
{
    public string Label { get; set; }

    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class EnumDescriptorTypeConverter<TSource> : ITypeConverter<TSource, EnumDescriptor<TSource>>
    where TSource: Enum
{
    public EnumDescriptor<TSource> Convert(TSource source, EnumDescriptor<TSource> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (source is null)
            return null;

        var enumDescriptor = new EnumDescriptor<TSource>
        {
            Label = source.GetDisplayName(),
            Value = System.Convert.ToInt32(source)
        };

        return enumDescriptor;
    }
}
```

And then i'm trying to register it following way:

```
serviceCollection
            .AddAutoMapper(options =>
            {
                options.CreateMap(typeof(Enum), typeof(EnumDescriptor<>))
                    .ConvertUsing(typeof(EnumDescriptorTypeConverter<>));

                options.AddMaps(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            });
```

Then I'm trying to cast enum value to **EnumDescriptor**:

```
_mapper.Map<EnumDescriptor<CurrentStatus>>(CurrentStatus.Active);
```

I'm getting an exception saying that:

> Cannot create an instance of typeEnumDescriptorTypeConverter`1[CurrentStatus]

Does anyone have that issue before?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm thinking that it's expecting your converter to be registered with your dependency injection container. That's my hunch anyway.

Comment: @John Can you please post an answer i'll mark as correct answer. Thanks

Comment: I recommend posting your own answer since you have the code to go with it :)

Comment: The generic type converter is registered automatically by `AddAutoMapper`. [Working code](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/pull/154/files#diff-9b13b9db319933f3dc56606dccc86dcdeafe1e0b73b173463ac50a21c53628b9R54).